# trying to wget a file from the web on my beaglebone

Tags: wget, beagleboard, angstrom-linux

I just got a beaglebone today, loaded with the angstrom distribution of linux, and have hit a wall. Here is what I have done since opening the box:

Downloaded and installed 64 bit windows driver from http://beagleboard.org/static/beaglebone/latest/README.htm to allow me to attach my beagleboard via USB.

Downloaded putty from http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Set up putty with my COM (COM8) and a speed of 115200, then opened up my serial USB terminal to interface with the beagleboard.

At this point, whenever I do a wget command such as:

```
wget http://example.com/file.py
```

I get an error of:

```
wget: bad address 'example.com'
```

I am connected to the internet via wireless... is there a port I should be opening up or something? It seem as though wget just can't get to the web at all.

Am I limiting myself because I am not connected to the internet via ethernet? If that's the case, am I better off downloading the files to my windows box and transferring them manually?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, not surprisingly, the wireless connection.

My windows machine was connected to the beaglebone via USB, and to the ethernet via wireless.

Plugging an ethernet cable into the beaglebone solved the problem. Still, I would like to be able to do it through my windows box.